# Tomcat: Treating multiple subdirectories as different domains to insulate sessions

Tags: session, tomcat, dns, subdirectory

I have an issue wherein multiple different kinds of logins in a Tomcat backend webapp are using the same session attribute names, so login properties are stomping over one another and logouts are indiscriminately clearing other logins' data.

I don't have separate domains (and arranging something to simulate multiple domains would be too large a hassle), but I'd like it if tomcat would treat files in different subdirectories as if they had different domains so I can keep session infos from battling.

As it stands, the most superficial fix (but not the quickest) would be going through and explicitly changing the session atttribute names so nothing conflicts.. I'd have to touch on a couple hundred files to guarantee my approach won't cause bugs. This would take far more time than it's worth.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deploy the webapp on each of those "subdirectories" (really known as "context paths"). Each context will be considered separate and the sessions will not interfere with each other.